# Cardinality of a set containing subsets of $\omega_{1}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Consider the set $ \{ X \subseteq \omega_{1} \ | \text{ such that }  |X| = \aleph_{0} \} $

I know $\omega$ is in this set. But then I thought about it and realized that {2,3,4,... } was also in this set, and it has cardinality $ \omega $ . The answer turns out to be $2^{\aleph_{0}}$. Is there a bijection from the set in question to $P(\omega) $ or is there a straight forward counting argument.

edit: Changed $2^{\omega} $ to $ 2^{\aleph_{0}} $.

Answer (score 5):

The quickest way to prove this is the computation 
$$
2^{\aleph_0}\leq |X|\leq{\aleph_1}^{\aleph_0}\leq(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}
=2^{\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}.
$$
An alternative approach is to first observe that a countable subset of $\omega_1$ cannot be cofinal in $\omega_1$, so your set $X$ is the union, over all infiniteordinals $\alpha<\omega_1$, of the sets $X_\alpha$ of infinite subsets of $\alpha$.  Since each such $\alpha$ is countably infinite, each $X_\alpha$ has the cardinality of the continuum.  So $X$ is the union of $\aleph_1$ sets of size $2^{\aleph_0}$, and therefore it also has size $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: I know that $\aleph_1\leq^*2^{\aleph_0}$--that is, that there is a surjection $2^{\aleph_0}\to\aleph_1$--but is that enough to conclude that $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}\leq\bigl(2^{\aleph_0}\bigr)^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: @CameronBuie Using the axiom of choice, a surjection $2^{\aleph_0}\to\aleph_1$ gives you an injection in the other direction, which then induces an injection from ${\aleph_1}^{\aleph_0}$ to $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}$.  (In the absence of the axiom of choice, not only this proof but the result itself fails, since the set $X$ in the question has cardinality $\geq\aleph_1$ in any case.)

Comment: Good. Glad I correctly understood the situation.